# SSRS: sorting in chart

Tags: reporting-services

I have got this chart here:

[image]

And I would like to sort by value asc.

[image]

I know that I can do this in the chart settings
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Go into your Category Group Properties:
   [image]
2. In the Sort tab, set the Sort by value to by the sum of your value.
   [image]

Comment: The Problem is I have got 3 Values.

Comment: @M.JAY Oh you added categories. Do you want them sorted by value within each category?

Comment: I have not added categories only values, see above in my question, I added a picture. I tried it like you showed me. I used this expression : `=iif(Fields!HM.Value > Fields!FM.Value, Fields!HM.Value, iif(Fields!HM.Value > Fields!FR.Value, Fields!HM.Value, iif(Fields!FM.Value > Fields!HM.Value, Fields!FM.Value, iif(Fields!FM.Value > Fields!FR.Value, Fields!FM.Value, Nothing))))` But this not helped me

Comment: @M.JAY sorry, I don't think there's a way to dynamically sort the order of the values within each category group.